# set Focus dynamically through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to trigger an event when user focus on the select element.
I cant edit the body code. So am trying to achieve it through JS in head oly. 
Its appreciable if I can add attribute to my select element even from Javascript in header tag.

I want alert to be shown when user clicks on select element. Help.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    window.onload = function()
    {   

        var f = document.getElementById("CheckForm");

        var temp = document.getElementById("CheckForm.t1");
        if(f.name == "CheckForm")
        {
          var temp1 = document.getElementById("t1");
          temp1.value = "Task";
        }
        if(document.getElementByd("t2").focus)
        {
            alert("hello");
        }       

    }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form name="CheckForm" id="CheckForm">
    t1: <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1"/>
    t2: <select id="t2">
        <option></option>
                    <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        </select>   
    t3: <input type="text" id="t3" name="t3"/>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: if user clicks on select box u want to show an alert message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("t2").setAttribute("onclick", "alert()");
```

Comment: can you help where to replace this line in my code? 
I actually need to submit form (document.formname.submit()) when the user clicks/places cursor on select/focus on select element.

Comment: Did it work for you? I am not able to achieve it. Please share fiddle link if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works good but to avoid seeing form reloading onclick of t2. Can we make it as onchange on t1? If you observe when the form loads I am checking value of t1 and changing it to 'Task'. So onchange operation is happening. But I tried to implement same logic on t1 for onchange. Its not happening. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
    var att=document.createAttribute("onclick");
    att.value="yourFunction()";         
    document.getElementById("t2").setAttributeNode(att);


function yourFunction(){
// your js code
}
```

Comment: Check this... is it ok for you ?  `var attText=document.createAttribute("onblur");
    attText.value="yourNewFunction()";         
 document.getElementById("t1").setAttributeNode(attText);     function yourNewFunction(){
document.getElementById("t1").value="Task";
}`

Answer (score 0):

use this, alert message will come when select box gets focus

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script>
        window.onload = function()
        {   

            var f = document.getElementById("CheckForm");

            var temp = document.getElementById("CheckForm.t1");
            if(f.name == "CheckForm")
            {
              var temp1 = document.getElementById("t1");
              temp1.value = "Task";
            }
            if(document.getElementById("t2").focus)
            {
                alert("hello");
            }   

            document.getElementById("t2").setAttribute("onfocus", "selectHiglight()");

        }

    var selectHiglight=function(){
        alert('select get hilghited');
    };

       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
        <form name="CheckForm" id="CheckForm">
        t1: <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1"/>
        t2: <select id="t2">
            <option></option>
                        <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>   
        t3: <input type="text" id="t3" name="t3"/>
       </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: No it dint work. It just shown alert as soon as the page loads.

Comment: comment alert box in second if statement

Comment: Did it work for you? I am not able to achieve it. Please share fiddle link if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works good but to avoid seeing form reloading onclick of t2. Can we make it as onchange on t1? If you observe when the form loads I am checking value of t1 and changing it to 'Task'. So onchange operation is happening. But I tried to implement same logic on t1 for onchange. Its not happening. Is it possible?

Comment: replace this line document.getElementById("t2").setAttribute("onfocus", "selectHiglight()"); to this one document.getElementById("t1").setAttribute("onchange", "selectHiglight()");

Comment: Ya I did the same. But it dint work. Yeah its not working even in the above fiddle link. I mean not able to see Highlight alert.

Comment: it works when u complete the change in t1 and press tab or move focus on another control

Comment: That is fine. My t1 is readonly and my doubt is why its not triggering though t1 value changed from null to 'task' during onload.